# Redirect 301 not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I recently change my url and I need to make 301 redirect from:

```
^auto-second-hand/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1
```

to

```
^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1
```

I try

```
RewriteRule ^auto-second-hand/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1 ^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1  [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
```

but it's not working also tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^auto-second-hand/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1 ^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: the older URL : http://www.autoside.ro/auto-second-hand/alba/
the new URL : http://www.autoside.ro/piata-auto/alba/

Comment: working .htaccess

RewriteRule ^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1
RewriteRule ^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/pagina-([0-9]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1&pag=$2

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^\^auto-second-hand/\(\[A-Za-z0-9,-\]\+\)/\$ afisare-judete\.php$ /^piata-auto/([A-Za-z0-9,-]+)/$ afisare-judete.php?judet=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much but it gives me error 500 "Internal Server error"

Comment: Edited the lines there

Comment: Nobody can help me? :(